# getting unique objects from array of nested object and sub properties

Tags: javascript

i have a script where i am trying to get the unique object based on state from the array of objects

The below scripts works fine, but I have one case where I have nested object in one kind of state has a sub-state, so I want to find the unique from the array of objects and get the unique.

The below snippet I am able to get the first level, but if we see the **state** => "EF" has a sub_state_details, so I need to get the unique from sub_state_details if state is **EF**

```js
let inputArray = [{
    state: "AB",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "DE",
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  },
  {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-2"
    }
  }
]

let resArr = []
inputArray.filter(function(item) {
  var i = resArr.findIndex(x => (x.state == item.state));
  if (i <= -1) {
    resArr.push({
      state: item.state
    });
  }
  return null;
});

console.log(resArr)
```

expected output

```
let output = [{
      state: "AB",
    }, {
      state: "BC",
    }, {
      state: "CD",
    }, {
      state: "DE",
    }, {
      state: "EF-1",
    },{
      state: "EF-2",
    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers may give you the correct result, but they are using array functions incorrectly, granted they are based on your attempt. e.g. some using `filter` but never using the result from the `filter`.  or trying to `return null` from a `forEach` even though `forEach` doesn't. return anything

`reduce()` is better suited to your case, as you are *reducing* one array to another, based on some conditions -

```js
let inputArray = [{
    state: "AB",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "DE",
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  },
  {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-2"
    }
  }
]

const result = inputArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(!acc.find((accItem) => accItem.state == cur.state)) {
    if(cur.state === 'EF') {
       if(cur.sub_state_details && !acc.find((accItem) => accItem.state === cur.sub_state_details.state)) {
          acc.push({state: cur.sub_state_details.state})
       }
    } else {
       acc.push({state: cur.state})
    }
    
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: you have added `if(cur.state == 'EF')` in the if condition, this is specific to 'EF' right, if state AB have substate. How it will behave?. We need to add one more condition in if statement

Comment: The question says - "The below snippet I am able to get the first level, but if we see the state => "EF" has a sub_state_details, so I need to get the unique from sub_state_details if state is EF"

Comment: But there are two EF-1s, only one is showing?

Comment: @Battledoosh look at the expected output in the OP, that's the expected behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional statement to check if `sub_state_details` exists.

Like this:

```js
let inputArray = [
  {
state: "AB",
  },
  {
state: "BC",
  },
  {
state: "BC",
  },
  {
state: "CD",
  },
  {
state: "CD",
  },
  {
state: "DE",
  },
  {
state: "EF",
sub_state_details: {
  state: "EF-1",
},
  },
  {
state: "EF",
sub_state_details: {
  state: "EF-1",
},
  },
  {
state: "EF",
sub_state_details: {
  state: "EF-2",
},
  },
];

let resArr = [];
inputArray.filter(function (item) {
  var i = resArr.findIndex((x) => x.state == item.state);
  if (i <= -1) {
if (item.sub_state_details) {
  resArr.push({
    state: item.sub_state_details.state,
  });
} else {
  resArr.push({
    state: item.state,
  });
}
  }
  return null;
});

console.log(resArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a pretty simple solution. You first have to check if `sub_state_details` exists. If it does, we need to use that `state` instead. We can achieve this by using a variable called "sub," and if the `sub_state_details` object is defined, we use `sub_state_details.state` instead of `item.state`.

```js
let inputArray = [{
    state: "AB",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "DE",
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  },
  {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-2"
    }
  }
]

let resArr = []
inputArray.filter(function(item) {
  var i = resArr.findIndex(x => (x.state == item.state));
  let sub = item.sub_state_details;
  if(!sub) {sub=item}
  if (i <= -1) {
    resArr.push({
      state: sub.state
    });
  }
  return null;
});

console.log(resArr)
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Gosh, I was just trying to help. What's the point of the -1?

Answer (score -1):

I have rewritten your code with some minor changes, that will solve your problem. Instead of checking only state, in the `findIndex` function, I have included one more condition for `sub_state_details` also if its present.

No need to worry about state & its sub-state, try code

```
var i = resArr.findIndex(x => 
  {
    return (x.state === item.state && ((x.sub_state_details && x.sub_state_details.state) ? x.sub_state_details.state === item.sub_state_details.state : true))
  });
```

Instead of directly pushing into the empty, check the array has sub-state details, push along with the array. Already we checked the state & substate are unique.

```
if(item.sub_state_details) {
      resArr.push({
        state: item.state,
        sub_state_details: item.sub_state_details
      });
    }
```

```js
let inputArray = [{
    state: "AB",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "BC",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "CD",
  }, {
    state: "DE",
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  }, {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-1"
    }
  },
  {
    state: "EF",
    sub_state_details: {
      state: "EF-2"
    }
  }
]

let resArr = []
inputArray.filter(function(item) {
  var i = resArr.findIndex(x => 
  {
    return (x.state === item.state && ((x.sub_state_details && x.sub_state_details.state) ? x.sub_state_details.state === item.sub_state_details.state : true))
  });
  if (i <= -1) {
    if(item.sub_state_details) {
      resArr.push({
        state: item.state,
        sub_state_details: item.sub_state_details
      });
    }
    else {
      resArr.push({
        state: item.state,
      });
    }
  }
  return null;
});

console.log(resArr);
```

I hope this would be useful.

Comment: your output does not match the expected output, and why are you using `filter()` when you dont do anything with the result from `filter()` ?

Comment: What makes this different then just straight up `console.log`ging the entire object?